# How to add hashmap to hashmap that alredy exists without overriding the information?

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.android

I want to make list (hashmap in hashmap) of usernames in the firsestore.
I don't want to run over the data in participants every time that Running the action.

```
HashMap innermap = new HashMap();
HashMap outmap= new HashMap();
DocumentReference documentReference =Signup2.Getdatabase(Context).Collection("teams").Document(userdata.GetString("teamcode", "0000"))
.Collection("workout").Document(position.GetString("workoutdateposition", ""));
innermap.Put("username", userdata.GetString("username", ""));
outmap.Put("participants", innermap);
documentReference.Set(outmap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to merge the data in your API call with the existing data in the document, you have two options:

1. Call the [`UpdateAsync` API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data)

   ```
    documentReference.UpdateAsync(outmap);
   ```
2. The `UpdateAsync` only works if the document already exists. If you don't know whether the document already exists or not, you can [call `Set` or `SetAsync` with `SetOptions.MergeAll`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document):

   ```
    documentReference. SetAsync(outmap, SetOptions.MergeAll);
   ```